# How can I use Sass variables with data attributes in HTML5

Tags: html, sass

I am trying to achieve a background color change when scrolling, so I need to use a `data-bg` attribute like this in my HTML markup:

```
<div class="section" data-bg="#ccff00">
```

How can I use a SCSS/Sass variable instead of the Hex code? For example:

```
<div class="section" data-bg="$background-color">
```

So when I change the variables this color also changes without having to change the HTML markup.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't. Sass compiles to CSS so any variables are localised to your Sass files. You could try a [package which exports to JSON](https://github.com/pmowrer/node-sass-json-importer) but things could get a bit messy this way.

Comment: Apparently, your JavaScript code doesn't use CSS (not at least in the usual way) so it's difficult to integrate with a CSS preprocessor. Is it a third-party library or something you can tweak? Because the cleanest approach would be to assign classes rather than hard-coded colours.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your variable into the `:root` selector (like **Bootstrap** do),
and use it with the `css` function `var()`.

```
:root {
  --bg-color: $background-color;
  --text-color: $text-color;
}
```

If you want to get the value using `jQuery` :

```js
jQuery(':root').css('--bg-color');
```

```css
 :root {
  --bg-color: #f00;
  --text-color: #0f0;
}

section {
  height: 100px;
  color: var(--text-color);
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
}
```

```html
<section>
Lorem ipsum ...
</section>
```

Comment: I understand there's JavaScript involved and the script is not actually using CSS.

Comment: I've added a `jQuery` sample.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot use sass Variables in Data Attribute directly but there is an indirect way of doing this.
In this way also you can change Variable from dark to light, and it will change the color from red to green.

But those both should be declared in your data-bg as i did. See this example.

```css
[data-bg='dark']{
    --text-color: red;
}
[data-bg='light']{
    --text-color: green;
}


div {
  color: var(--text-color);
}
```

```html
    <div data-bg="light"> testing green</div>
    <div data-bg="dark"> testing red</div>
```

Comment: Yes, there is JS involved: 
document.body.style.background = window.sections[0].getAttribute('data-bg');

Answer (score 0):

An instance of data-bg attribute you can use style attribute to store the variable.
In html:

```
<div class="section" style="--data-bg:#ccff00">
```

and in scss:

```
.section{
  $bg: var(--data-bg);
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: $bg;
}
```